# SVG nav-link in a Bootstrap navbar, cross-browser

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 navbar with nav-links in it and I'd like one of those links to show an SVG instead of text.

Specifically, it's a link to Patreon and I'd like it to appear as the Patreon logo.

I've already done so and this is how it shows on Chrome:

[image]

There it's pretty much doing what I want it to.

But things are different on Firefox:

[image]

And on my own iPhone4 the svg shows very very tiny but I'm guessing that's because I'm on a very old system (iOS7).

Here are the relevant portions of my CSS.

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.patreon-wordmark.svg-icon svg {
    height: 1.6em;
    width: auto;
}

.patreon-wordmark.svg-icon.svg-baseline svg {
    bottom: -0.53em;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And for other svg's elsewhere I also have this code (thought I'd put it here in case it interferes with the rest somehow):

```
.svg-icon {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-self: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
}
.svg-icon svg {
    height:1em;
    width:1em;
}
.svg-icon.svg-baseline svg {
    bottom: -0.125em;
    position: absolute;
}
```

My SVG is inline and contained like so:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link patreon-wordmark svg-icon svg-baseline" href="link">
        <svg ...
```

**What to do to get them to align the same in all browsers? Or am I approaching the problem wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I took a different road.

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link navbar-patreon-svg" href="http://www.patreon.com/antoineguenet">
        <span class="text-hide" >Patreon</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-patreon-svg {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    mask: url(../images/patreon-wordmark-black.svg);
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-size: contain;
    mask-origin: content-box;
    -webkit-mask: url(../images/patreon-wordmark-black.svg);
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-size: contain;
    -webkit-mask-origin: content-box;

    min-width: 7em;
}
```

And as a final touch, to make the svg change color on hover like the rest of the links:

```
.navbar-patreon-svg:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```